# How do I stop my phone from turning off the display whenever I put my finger over the phone speaker?

Tags: ios, screen, iphone

I have an iPhone 6, and recently I've found out that if you put your finger on the thing next to the front camera, the display will turn black. but I can't find a setting to turn it off. Anyone know where it is? Or if I can? This isn't just calls it's anytime.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case, it was just a bug. All you need to do to fix this is to restart your iPhone and it should be fixed. Thanks to Apple support.

Comment: I was running into this issue on my iPhone X and restarting it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The proximity sensor next to the front camera/speaker engages when it believes the device is being held to your face. Holding your finger over it causes the same effect.

There is no way to disable the proxmity sensor.

Comment: I think it's the proximity sensor, not ambient light, right?

Comment: You're probably right, though it maybe a combination of them.

Comment: I lol'd from that one!

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to bypass the camera blacking out my screen: lock your screen and put a piece of black tape over the camera. Open phone, problem solved.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe turn off facial recognition because the proximity sensor won't be looking for your face. I don't know however

Comment: This question is for an iPhone 6, not the iPhone X.