# iPhone turns off display whenever covering the proximity sensor

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, screen

I have an iPhone 7. Sometimes when I put my finger on the proximity sensor (besides front speaker), the display turns black. I can't find a setting to turn it off. Anyone know where it is? Or if I can?

This doesn't just happen when a call is in progress (which is expected behaviour), it happens anytime. Restarting the iPhone didn't resolve the issue, it start appearing again after a day or two.

Comment: @Nimesh I have verified that the screen goes black when on a call and anything blocks the sensor next to the speaker, but the screen does not go black when not making a call and the sensor is blocked. I am deleting my previous comments as I do not think they add anything to help answer this question.

Comment: I understand you have tried restarting your phone but have you tried force restarting? This is because a similar post [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259151/how-do-i-stop-my-phone-from-turning-off-the-display-whenever-i-put-my-finger-ove) describes the same problem and claims a restart fixed it. Also would you be able to let us know what version of IOS you are on? Is it the most up to date? If it's really bothering you, you could back up your iPhone and try a factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why this may be happening:

- You have a case or screen protector that interferes with the proximity sensor. If so then try to remove them.
- Do a force restart of your device. Press and hold both the Side and Volume Down buttons for at least 10 seconds, until you see the Apple logo.

If that doesn't work then take your iPhone to an Apple Store.